# Unknown display passed to Tk_CreateErrorHandler

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a Python/Tk script which, sometime to time generate this error :
"Unknown display passed to Tk_CreateErrorHandler"

I'm using the application through a ssh tunnel on a remote Linux machine with an exported display.
I understand the reason of this error, but I assume that it's generated because it need to display another, real, problem.

How can I solve this ?

How to say to "Tk_CreateErrorHandler" to use my exported display (or better, if possible, $DISPLAY variable) ?

Thanks in advance

ericc

Comment: Show trackback and some code.

Comment: Well, if only I knew which code create this error ...

Comment: Add to question full error message (trackback) - there is filename and number of line with problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get `DISPLAY` variable:

```
import os

print os.getenv("DISPLAY")
```

but I don't know how to use it with `Tk_CreateErrorHandler`

Comment: This is already a first step ... I guess now that I will have to pass this value to Tk